# Device Locking in Android

Tags: android, locking, lockscreen

I need to lock my phone without using the device physical button.  I created an `Activity` that contains a `Button`. Clicking the `Button` should lock the phone (i.e it should be like this http://www.freeimagehosting.net/2dcaf)

Can any one help me whit this?  And the thing is it is not possible using keyguard manager or power manager because it is disabling and enabling the locking system.

Currently the code is done but some bugs are occuring... Here is my code

```
dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);     
dpm.lockNow();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying....android 2.0 and upper i f its possible in the lower versions also i can try in emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 2.2 (I think) you can use `DevicePolicyManager`:

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

and then:

```
devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
```

*Edit:*

For this solution you have to add a device admin e.g.:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);  
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, securemeAdmin);
```

Comment: thnaks for the Reply... i have a question i am not able to use DevicePolicyManger in my Eclipse......

Comment: Thanx i am getting now.. But som error are occurring  if u can suggest me any thing please help me...........here is the errors http://www.freeimagehosting.net/cdfb5

Comment: @C V Sukesh: You have to add a device admin (see edit in answer).

Comment: Thanks simson i am trying in android 2.2 itself.... It is not working in the 2.1 and below versions. I am trying still.... I wil let u know when i complte this

Comment: Only in <2.2 or in 2.2 as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PowerManager` api. Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). Call `goToSleep` method.

Comment: "And the thing is it is not possible using keygaurd manager or power manager because it is disabling and enabling the locking system"

Comment: But `goToSleep` documentation says it forces the device to sleep. And when user activity occurs, the lock screen will appear. Right?